# Gradle: regex to find and replace whitespace around specific text

Tags: java, regex, string, gradle

I'm using Gradle to parse a SQL file that has "GO" (or "go") separating commands. The JDBC driver doesn't like "go", so I break the file out using "go" as a separator. I was using

```
multiLineString.replaceAll("(?i)\ngo\n","\nGO\n").split("\nGO\n")
```

and while this is case-insensitive, it doesn't consider leading or trailing whitespace (sometimes spaces, sometimes tabs). If someone has a space (or tab) before or after "go", the replaceAll doesn't catch it.

I was hoping to use a regex to basically say, "if the only non-whitespace characters on a line are 'go', then change the line to '\nGO\n' so I can split it". I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
multiLineString.replaceAll (/\n\s+go\s+\n/, "\nGO\n").split("\nGO\n")
```

The multiLineString could contain text like:

```
drop procedure if exists dbo.procname
go
create procedure dbo.procname as
begin
....
```

... and I would want an array with two string back:

```
[0] drop procedure if exists dbo.procname
[1] create procedure dbo.procname as\nbegin\n ...
```

I need that same array even if the "go" is surrounded by leading,trailing spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may directly split with

```
multiLineString.split("(?i)\n[\\p{Zs}\t]*go[\\p{Zs}\t]*\n")
```

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - inline `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` modifier version
- `\n`  - a newline
- `[\\p{Zs}\t]*`  - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `go`   - a word `go`
- `[\\p{Zs}\t]*`  - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `\n`  - a newline

Also, if you expect the horizontal whitespace to be just regular spaces or tabs, you may replace `[\\p{Zs}\t]*` with `[ \t]*`.